# Is there a way to automatically reload node-inspector when server restarts?

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

It's a fairly small thing, but it feels like I'm manually refreshing the node-inspector tab in chrome a million times a day, and there must be a better way.

When a file changes, and node restarts, and node-inspector detaches from target -- is there a way for it to automatically re-attach itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [How can I make node-inspector restart when node is restarted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853443/how-can-i-make-node-inspector-restart-when-node-is-restarted/19930899). See the accepted answer for a workaround solution using GreaseMonkey.

There is also a GitHub issue filled in the Node Inspector project: [#266](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/266).

Answer (score 0):

Here's instructions to have a Node console (not REPL), while using nodemon, with a server output console, all from within VSCode.

[Node.js debugging in VS Code with Nodemon](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/nodemon)

The only thing to look out for is that it needs to be started manually with

`nodemon --inspect ./bin/www`

You can't let `nodemon` use your `package.json` `start` defaults because it won't restart.

The only thing this lacks is a webpage restart (if you're using web front end) but that's a whole other question.