# Debugging Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-inspector

I am using node-debug to debug a Node.js program.

```
node-debug my-program.js
```

It spins up an instance of Chrome inspector connected to the running Node.js program via a WebSocket.

When I make a change to `my-program.js` and refresh the inspector, then I find the inspector has been disconnected, meaning I have to restart it. The following message is displayed:

> Remote debugging has been terminated with the reason: "web_socket
>   closed". Please re-attach to the new target.

How can I avoid having to continually restart the inspector?

Comment: The linked question does not make it clear how to actually avoid this issue  with the updated node-inspector. Instead it links to a comment history on GitHub (which does not contain an obvious solution to the problem).

Comment: Check the third reply http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853443/how-can-i-make-node-inspector-restart-when-node-is-restarted/19930899#19930899