# How to auto connect after `reconnect when ready by reopening devtools`

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, nodemon

I am using the new `--inspect` to develop with node and I must say its hugely annoying to have to click the `reconnect` button after every single js change in my node application when using `nodemon`

[image]

Is there any way to have this automatically connect once the server has restarted?

Or even add a delay so every second it trys to reconnect if its not?

Comment: This could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44407773/3244654 if you are using https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: I know this is an old one but I usually first start my program with `--inspect --debug-brk` then open chrome 61 then open the url: `chrome://inspect` click `Open dedicated DevTools for Node` and it automatically re attaches to the process when I restart the node process